# How to implement CLI client to golang daemon?

Tags: algorithm, design-patterns, go

I have a linux daemon with http api which I have wrote on golang. At start he initialize variables and all time when I ask api - he is answer. Init is hard operation: read many config's, add many object's etc.

My problem that if main process die I can't use http api ;). My code isn't perfect and sometimes he stack or die, or user's disable linux service. But I still need some low level functionality to work.

If I try to implement all functions of web api at cli: his start will be very slow and hard for system. But I have more problem if implementation will be separated between CLI & web api: **inconsistent.** For example: I can start inside web api create && at same time inside CLI - delete all. I must implement lock function to prevent this. (I think write code at this side isn't good)

I don't use database server (and don't need). Maybe I can store inside files or use some shared memory?

**My question is how can I share object's data between golang daemon and CLI-client?**

Comment: Don't do that. Either have the CLI app talk to your API or have them both use a common database. You can create all sorts of IPC sync for this but you are going the wrong way.

Comment: I want talk with daemon api not from network. But I don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go has a built-in [RPC system](http://www.zeromq.org/) for easy communication between Go processes. You could also take a look at [0mq](http://www.zeromq.org/), or using [D-Bus](https://github.com/guelfey/go.dbus).